# Dialogflow (Send Text Message through Twilio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, dialogflow-es

I am trying to send text message from Dialogflow.
Here is what I have in my fullfillment:

```
    var accountSid = 'A**********************'; 
    var authToken = 'f**********************';   

    var twilio = require('twilio');
    var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

    client.messages.create({
          body: 'Hello from me',
          to: '+1(phone-number)',  // Text this number
          from: '+1(phone-number)' // From a valid Twilio number
   })
  .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

I want to setup the intent so that the phrase can be triggered and automatically the Bot sends a text message (notification).

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Dialogflow's [fulfillment nodejs library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs). From the [Quick Start sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/samples/quick-start/functions/index.js), you can see how intent names are mapped to function handlers based on the intent map:

```
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
```

To send a text message, just add your SMS-sending code to a function and then map it to an intent name via the `intentMap`. Enable webhook fulfillment for this intent in Dialogflow's UI and the webhook will be called whenever the intent is matched.